# How to order queries in sql in flutter?

Tags: sql, flutter

I am using sqlite database in Flutter. with **provide** and **sqlite** libraries. I want to get ordered list of String in the database when I get the list from sqlite. How can I achieve this? Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `orderBy` variable inside query method like this:

```
Future<List<SingleShiftModel>> getShiftModelsForParticularGroup(
      String groupId) async {
    Database db = await database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query(
      allShiftsTableName,
      where: 'parentId = ?',
      orderBy: "date ASC", // here you can add your custom order exactly like sqlite but EXCLUDE `ORDER BY`.
      whereArgs: [groupId],
    );

    return List.generate(
      maps.length,
      (i) => SingleShiftModel.toShiftModelObject(maps[i]),
    );
  }
```